# After associating superuser at stackoverflow, other associations are gone

Tags: bug, status-completed, association

I have accesed the superuser.com site and logged in with my Google based OpenID.
Then I wanted to associate the superuser with the stackoverflow user.
I went to Stackoverflow and selected 'Associate with Superuser.com' this went well, however my stackoverflow user does not know the serverfault or meta.stackoverflow users anymore, and when I try to associate I get a 'Cannot associate, because it is allready associated'.

Here are my user id's:
Stackoverflow: 47860 (knows superuser)
Meta: 129989 (knows serverfault)
Serverfault: 13724 (knows meta)
SuperUser: 4655 (knows stackoverflow).

So I have two pairs of associated users instead of one carré.

EDIT:
 After comment of Jeff (2009-08-07)
Some more info:
When I am in superuser and I associate with either meta or serverfault I loose my association with serverfault and visa versa.

Ton

Comment: I suspect you are using two different Google accounts?

Comment: I don't see any associations on your account http://stackoverflow.com/users/47860?tab=accounts#sort-top

Comment: It is fixed (I think the hard-way) by Jarrod Dixon.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've fixed your associations - it's due to how Google makes this process a complete pain.

In the future, it would be best to clear all associations between accounts and start over.

Answer (score 0):

Possibly something to do with the fact that [Google OpenIDs are hashed per domain](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2009/04/googles-openids-are-unique-per-domain/)?

Answer (score 0):

This is a bug in association that was new today, and has already been fixed. Try again.

Comment: Nope, as soon as I try to associate superuser and stackoverflow it falls apart.

Ton